# Defining a special Ord for a data type in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I just couldn't find out how can I implement a special ord for my datatypes in haskell. I read on the forum, that it should look somewhat like this:

```
import Data.Set

data Cord = Cord { x :: Int
                 , y :: Int} deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance Eq Cord where
    (Cord a b) == (Cord a b) = (a==c and b==d) 

instance Ord Cord where
    compare (Cord a b) (Cord c d) = if a==c then compare (b d) else compare(a c)
```

I want to create a simple type with 2 integers, and one is larger then the other if his first number is larger then the other ones first number, or the second ones if the firsts are equal. I know that this comparison can be done by creating lists of 2 integers, however i wan't to some lot more complex data types and can't find anywhere a guide how to define an ord with if-s and recursions.

Thank you for your anwser!

Answer (score 3):

I think your real issue is that you've used `deriving (Eq, Ord)`, which implies that you already have a derived typeclass instance for `Ord`.  If you remove that and use your comparison, it seems fine:

```
data Cord = Cord { x :: Int, y :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Cord where
  compare (Cord a b) (Cord c d) = if a == c then compare b d else compare a c
```

In GHCI:

```
*Main> compare (Cord 4 2) (Cord 9 6)
LT
*Main> compare (Cord 3 2) (Cord 3 0)
GT
*Main> compare (Cord 2 2) (Cord 2 2)
EQ
```

Answer (score 2):

One helpful thing for `Ord` is its instance of `Monoid` so you can combine your case like this

```
instance Ord Coordinate where
    compare (Coord x1 x2) (Coord y1 y2) = (compare x1 y1) <> (compare x2 y2)
```

you might need to `import Data.Monoid` in order to have `(<>)` at your hands.
This "trick" enables you to abstract the traversing/if-then-elsing/recursing over your data structure from the actual operation of comparing the sub results.

If you tell me what your datatype is - I could (maybe) give you more concrete hints how to do this.

---

### Edit

A bit more explanation on the `Monoid` thing:

A Monoid is a datastructure that has an ([associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)) operation `<>` that allows you to combine  two datastructures and a neutral element `mempty` that has the following property:

```
 x <> mempty = x
 mempty <> x = x
```

the easiest example you can think of is your data structure being the good old list `[a]` then where the combination operator is just concatenation of lists `(<>) = (++)` and the neutral element is the empty list `mempty = []`.

For the `Ord` the combination is slightly more complicated - `compare` yields something of type `Ordering` which is just one of `EQ|LT|GT` so we have to define two things for it to be a `Monoid`

```
 mempty = EQ
 LT <> _ = LT
 GT <> _ = GT
 EQ <> x = x
```

`Monoid`s are a quite convenient way of abstracting things so they are a neat trick to have up your sleeve.

Comment: seems like overengineering to use `Data.Monoid` for such a trivial, isolated, concrete task... especially if all it's about is the extraneous `deriving` clause.

Comment: in this case I have to disagree - well not entirely if you can derive the `Ord` instance without problems, it is the easiest method - but the question was - for a more complicated data-structure, thus I gave advice on creating an `Ord` instance on your own. One use-case where I ran into problems when I had an infinite list in my data-structure, which lead to an infinite calculation when the data structures were the same, thus I had to craft the `Eq` and `Ord` instance by hand. And I have to admit that I simply overlooked the deriving clause, as no error message was provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an instance of a typeclass with any functions you like (that have the correct signature).

As an example:

```
newtype LexInt = LexInt [Int] -- ints in reverse digit order
instance Eq LexInt where
    (==) (LexInt (l:ls)) (LexInt (r:rs)) = (l == r) && ((LexInt ls) == (LexInt rs))
    (==) (LexInt []) (LexInt []) = True
    (==) _ _ = False
```